# Type generated in temporary asp.net files that no longer exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 3 project that has started giving me a build error

```
The type or namespace name 'ActivityItemViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This error is coming from an ASP.net temporary files

It appears to be referencing a type  that no longer exists in the project.  This type was removed a long time ago and the application has been build/bracnhed release many times since then.

```
 public class views_activities_activityfeeditem_ascx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ActivityItemViewModel>
```

Neither the view or the view model exists any more.

I assumed that the temp file was corrupt and deleted them this worked the first time I rebuilt but after that i get the same error.

I've tried.

- Cleaning solution and rebuild
- Deleting temporary asp.net files (both normal and 64 bit)
- Stop IIS/Clean delete and rebuild Start IIS
- And a load of combinations of the above

This worked the first time but now I get the error every time.  Not sure how asp.net is getting a reference to these types?

Any help or guidance on debugging this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with:  Ctrl+Shift+F, Entire solution, ActivityItemViewModel

Comment: Should have mentioned yes I have done that.  Nothing comes back as expected.

Comment: Did you try to specify the ViewModel with absolute namespace? Like `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<YourNamespace.ActivityItemViewModel>`. For me worked that once, but I needed to update any ascx and do all the cleanup tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.

In desperation I decided to add a view and model to project with those names.  TFS said that i could not as file already existed.  The file was not in file system or TFS explorer.  I deleted local project and got latest and the file was there on file system. I deleted the file  and it all worked dam you TFS!!!

Answer (score 0):

On the top of the class you must have a path to a view. Check that view for any errors. It has happen to me that by mistake I have introduced characters before the using statements, giving an error when trying to retrieve the model.

Answer (score 0):

**I've tried.**

1. Unload/Reload project.
2. Cleaning/rebuild solution and
3. bin/obj from project

**This working.**